# NGINX 444 response equivalent for Apache server

Tags: apache, nginx

How can I configure Apache HTTPD server to send no response and close connection in case of DDoS or malicious request

Answer (score 3):

HTTP status code 444 is simply an internal response that indicates NGINX has closed the connection without response. This is a non-standard code and is not sent to the requesting client. Often, 403 Forbidden is the equivalent used in Apache.

To generate an error in response to DoS or other attacks, you will need a script on either NGINX or Apache that responds to a set of configured rules.

In NGINX, this is often done with `ngx_http_limit_req_module`.

In Apache, this is commonly done using a combination of the `mod_security` and `mod_evasive modules`.

There are a number of good tutorials on how to set this up given your environment.